# Problem installing Ubuntu 11.10 on new laptop

Tags: 11.10, windows, ati, nomodeset

I bought a Toshiba Sattellite L755D-12F two days ago with Windows 7. I wanted to install Ubuntu 11.10, but whenever I boot it from a live cd or USB I get a blank screen.

Now i've seen similar topics around the internet, but I can't get wiser out of it. (Something about pressing F6 and Nomodeset.)

Does someone know a link to a good tutorial, or is it possible to prepare my AMD driver for Linux within Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the instructions:

In grup menu, press <kbd>e</kbd>.
Then find the "quiet splash" words and change it with "nomodeset" (if your graphics card is nvidia) or "radeon.modeset=0" (if radeon).
Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> button conbination to continue with the changes you have just made.

It would help you maybe.